# Why is my Actor created 2 times

Tags: scala, akka

I wrote this code

```
class TestActor extends Actor {
   override def preStart(): Unit = {
      println("going to start my test actor")
   }

   override def postStop(): Unit = {
      println("came inside stop")
   }

   def receive = {
      case msg: TestMessage => sender ! s"Hello ${msg.name}"
   }
}

object TestActor {
   val props = Props(new TestActor)
   case class TestMessage(name: String)
}
```

I call it using this client code

```
object MyApp extends App {
   val ac = ActorSystem("TestActorSystem")
   val a = new ClassA(ac).sayHello()
   val b = new ClassB(ac).sayHello()
   for {
      msg1 <- a
      msg2 <- b
   } {
      println(msg1)
      println(msg1)
   }
   Await.result(ac.terminate(), Duration.Inf)
}

class ClassA(ac: ActorSystem) {
   def sayHello(): Future[String] = {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
      val actor = ac.actorOf(TestActor.props)
      val msg = actor ? TestActor.TestMessage("foo")
      msg.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
   }
}

class ClassB(ac: ActorSystem) {
   def sayHello() : Future[String]  = {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
      val actor = ac.actorOf(TestActor.props)
      val msg = actor ? TestActor.TestMessage("bar")
      msg.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
   }
}
```

I see the output

```
going to start my test actor
going to start my test actor
Hello foo
Hello foo
came inside stop
came inside stop
```

My question is that in the companion object I had created the props object as a val and therefore there was only 1 val and that 1 val had 1 instance of `new TestActor`

In the client both classes used the same instance of actor system. Therefore there should have been only 1 actor and both messages from classA and ClassB should have gone to the same actor.

But it seems that both classes got their own Actor instances.

Comment: What should `Props(new TestActor)` do? I struggle to understand which of the `Props` constructor you want to use. 
Also, every call to `system.actorOf` creates a new instance of that actor. If you want to create your actor just once, you might as well just create it outside of `ClassB` and `ClassA` and pass it to them like you do with the ActorSystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is that in the companion object I had created the props object as a val and therefore there was only 1 val and that 1 val had 1 instance of `new TestActor`

Not really. Yes, you define one `val`, but that `val` is a `Props`. The `Props` class is essentially a recipe for creating an actor. What you're defining is a single immutable recipe for creating a `TestActor`. This recipe can be used multiple times, which is what you're doing when you call `ac.actorOf(TestActor.props)` twice. Both of these calls use the same `Props` recipe to create a new `TestActor`; that is, you use the same recipe to create two `TestActor` instances.

To reuse a single `TestActor`, do what @mfirry suggested and create this actor outside of `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Here's one way to do that:

```
object MyApp extends App {
  val ac = ActorSystem("TestActorSystem")

  val testActor = ac.actorOf(TestActor.props)

  val a = new ClassA(ac).sayHello(testActor)
  val b = new ClassB(ac).sayHello(testActor)
  for {
    msg1 <- a
    msg2 <- b
  } {
    println(msg1)
    println(msg1)
  }
  Await.result(ac.terminate(), Duration.Inf)
}

class ClassA(ac: ActorSystem) {
  def sayHello(actor: ActorRef): Future[String] = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
    val msg = actor ? TestActor.TestMessage("foo")
    msg.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
  }
}

class ClassB(ac: ActorSystem) {
  def sayHello(actor: ActorRef): Future[String]  = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
    val msg = actor ? TestActor.TestMessage("bar")
    msg.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `actorOf` will create a new actor, so for twice `actorOf` it will create 2 `TestActor`. you can use `actorSelection` to avoid the second creation, like:

```
class ClassA(ac: ActorSystem) {
  def sayHello(): Future[String] = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
    val actor = ac.actorOf(Props[TestActor], "test")
    println(actor.path)
    val msg = actor ? TestMessage("foo")
    msg.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
  }
}

class ClassB(ac: ActorSystem) {
  def sayHello() : Future[String]  = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
    val actor = ac.actorSelection("akka://TestActorSystem/user/test")
    val msg = actor ? TestMessage("bar")
    msg.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
  }
}
```